# performance / computing time optimization for dealing with huge tables

Tags: performance-tuning, finite-element-method, list-manipulation

I'm currently coding a Finite Element Method (FEM) program in Mathematica. For the so called stiffness matrix I need a very large table preferably around the size of 10^6 x 10^6 cells that are all zero at first.

For a smaller Table 10^4 x 10^4, I used the following code:

```
Timing[k=Table[0, {i, 1, 10^4}, {j, 1, 10^4}];]
```

and got results around 0.9 - 1.0 seconds

since ((10^6)^2)/((10^4)^2) = 10^4 I would expect a computing time of roughly 10000 seconds (~2.7 hours) for a 10^6 x 10^6 table which is frankly put, too slow.

I tried `ParallelTable` as well, but it's only like 30% faster

Is there a faster way to generate such a big array?

Comment: `k = ConstantArray[0, {10^6, 10^6}, SparseArray]`

Comment: .. or `k = SparseArray[{}, {10^6, 10^6}]`?

Comment: @Coolwater, kglr exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Coolwater and kglr have commented SparseArray was exactly what I was looking for!

```
k = ConstantArray[0, {10^6, 10^6}, SparseArray]

k = SparseArray[{}, {10^6, 10^6}]
```

both do the job.